# How to use fetch API with CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

I've built a serverless react website for a bar, and the beer listing is retrieved (as XML) via a fetch request:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://****************/taplist.xml'
        const proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

        this.setState({
          isLoading: true
        })
        fetch(proxyURL + url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(beerXML => {
          let beerJs = new XMLParser().parseFromString(beerXML)
          this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            beers: beerJs
          })
        })

      }
```

This was working fine, but recently the API has been failing. No data is returned, and I'm getting the following error in the browser:

```
Home.jsx:27 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://************/taplist.xml 403 (Forbidden)
bundle.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at bundle.js:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e.value (bundle.js:1)
    at e.value (bundle.js:1)
    at Home.jsx:30
```

I suspect that the 'Cors anywhere' proxy is failing and therefore not returning any data. I logged the variable `beerXML` to the console which should have showed the beer data, but didn't yield anything.

Can anyone suggest a tweak to my current API call, or maybe suggest a new proxy to use? Or any other approach that may fix this?

Here's the whole component responsible for fetching and rendering the data:

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import hashi_logo_2 from './Photos/hashi_logo_2.png'
import TileList from './TileList'
import OnNextList from './OnNextList'
import Nav from './Nav'
import twitter_logo from './Photos/twitter_logo.png'
import facebook_logo from './Photos/facebook_logo.png'
const XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser')

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          beers:[],
          isLoading:false
        }
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://******************/taplist.xml'
        const proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

        this.setState({
          isLoading: true
        })
        fetch(proxyURL + url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(beerXML => {
          console.log(`this is beerJs: ${beerXML}`)
          let beerJs = new XMLParser().parseFromString(beerXML)
          this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            beers: beerJs
          })
        })

      }

    render() {

    return (
        <div className = 'home'>
            <div className = 'home-nav'>
                <Nav/>
            </div>
              <main>
                  <div className='main__image'>
                      <img src= {hashi_logo_2}/>
                  </div>
              </main>
                <div>
                  {this.state.isLoading === false ?
                    <TileList beerList = {this.state.beers}/> 
                    :
                    <h1 className = 'loading-h1'>Loading tap beers....</h1>
                  }
                </div>
                <div className = 'on-next-section'>
                <OnNextList beerList = {this.state.beers}/>
                </div>
                <footer>
                  <a href = 'https://twitter.com/*********'>
                  <img className = 'img-footer' src = {twitter_logo} ></img>
                  </a>
                  <a href ='https://www.facebook.com/*******'>
                  <img className = 'img-footer' src = {facebook_logo} ></img>
                  </a>
                </footer>

        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Home
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the end server and not the proxy server. since it's a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: If you go to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, you will see that you should not use it for production (it is written in plain text). You either need to configure server where your xml located to configure access-control-allow-origin and allow you to fetch directly, or to use some other proxy, or even make your own.

Comment: can try with postman first, brother

Answer (score -2):

I simply used another proxy, and that fixed the problem:

```
const proxyURL = 'https://cors.bridged.cc/'
```

Comment: what do you do when that no longer accepts random requests from everyone on the internet? Also, you do realise, as a proxy, they have access to ALL data you send and receive using their "service" - how well do you trust them?